# Get Value from Dynamic User Control  On PostBack Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I created an item user_control that has a textbox, button, etc. which will intentionally collect the total quantity of items the user wants.

I dynamically create a few intances of user_control on page_load. If you click the add button for the item quantity it will add to a session variable. however when the user enters a different quantity in the textbox and clicks the add button the total is of the original value of the textbox.

How to get the value the the user has typed in to the textbox to add to total???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the same ID to the dynamic control after each postback, when you recreate the control. If you don't assign it the same ID, ViewState cannot populate the value.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "txt1"; 

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);            
}
```

Comment: ok. It is a TextBox in the User_Control. So I assign it in the usercontrol page_load or the Page i put the user_control in?

Comment: If the user control is dynamic, then Page_Load in the `Page`. If the TextBox is dynamic, then in the Page_Load in the `User Control`

Comment: do i have to recreate all the controls in the user control when i add the user control to the page dynamically?

Comment: ok i did that. When i try to grab the value of the textbox inside the intance of user control on post back (Dim Tbox as TextBox = UserControl_1.FindControl("TextBox1") I get the original text that it started with which in this case was "1" instead of the value that the user typed in.

Comment: Are you assigning the same ID to the user control on postback?

Comment: I have reposted the question with code [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389254/dynamic-usercontrols-on-postback-asp-net)

Comment: @tmax: I'll take a look. In the future, can just edit the question instead of posting a new question though. ;)