# how to get values from dynamically created textboxes?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I dynamically create textboxes by a click of a button... then i would like to get the values from the textboxes that i created to insert to the database..  I use VB.NET 2008.

this are some sample codes..

```
   For x As Integer = 0 To mydt.Rows.Count - 1

            l = New Label()
            tb = New TextBox()

            tb.ID = x.ToString()
            l.ID = x.ToString
            l.Text = bb

            Panel1.Controls.Add(l)
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb)

            tb.Text = mydt.Rows(x).Item(0)

        Next
```

Comment: what is that ID.? Text boxes are only having name to identify it right.?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am using ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I just assumed that you are working in winforms, You can do it by assigning unique name to your text boxes like this,

```
   For x As Integer = 0 To mydt.Rows.Count - 1

        l = New Label()
        tb = New TextBox()

        tb.name = "txt" & x 'Name your text box

        tb.ID = x.ToString()
        l.ID = x.ToString
        l.Text = bb

        Panel1.Controls.Add(l)
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb)

        tb.Text = mydt.Rows(x).Item(0)
   Next
```

So in the next step, since you are adding those textboxes in to panel1, you can fetch it directly from that container like below,

```
   For x As Integer = 0 To mydt.Rows.Count - 1
     MsgBox(Ctype( panel1.Controls("txt" & x),textbox).text)
   Next
```

Comment: @bolekevora Then please add ASP.net tag in your question.

Comment: Sorry i dont have any ideas regarding ASP.NET. Have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389254/dynamic-usercontrols-on-postback-asp-net